# SQL Server Analysis Services - using IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions

Tags: sql, ssas, analysis, dimensions, cubes

I have a question about the possiblity of show a message in case of having unrelated dimensions.

I'm using the IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions FALSE to have null or blank values, but I'm investigating about the possibility of showing some message when it happens instead of null or blank values. It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it; however, I vote against it. See review of proposed solution below. Solution is possible with *SCOPE* statement, but with some limitations.
Assume you have a cube with two dimensions, *A* and *B* and a measure *M*, not related to dimension *B*. Also, dimension *B* has two attributes, *b1* and *b2*. Then you can design the following *SCOPE* statement

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[M]);  
    SCOPE([Dim B].[b1].[b1]); THIS="message"; END SCOPE;
    SCOPE([Dim B].[b2].[b2]); THIS="message"; END SCOPE;  
END SCOPE;
```

This *SCOPE* will show `message` when you try to add analysis on *b1* or *b2* attribute. Note *[Dim B].[b1].[b1]* - we do not want our scope message show at *[Dim B].[b1].[All]* member.
Now let's review disadvantages of this approach.

1. You have to list **all** hierarchies of **all** unrelated dimensions. Tedious and error prone.
2. If you add both *Dim A* and *Dim B* to your query, figures will show only at *Dim B* aggregate level.

Basically, this solution replaces total figure of *IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions=true* with custom message at price of manually listing all unrelated dimensions and its hierarchies.